# Not able to use roscd command as it gives error

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error when I use roscd:

```
Inspiron-5559:~$ roscd beginner_tutorials
roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'
```

But everytime when I source the setup.bash file then it works:

```
Inspiron-5559:~/catkin_ws$ . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
Inspiron-5559:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
```

Then

```
Inspiron-5559:~/catkin_ws$ roscd beginner_tutorials
Inspiron-5559:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials$
```

Hence I need to source the file everytime for roscd to work..How do I remove this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279624/not-able-to-use-roscd-command-as-it-gives-error/) by [nrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33066/nrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you have to `source` your workspace everytime. If you're working with only one workspace add

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

to your `.bashrc` file and every time you open a new terminal your workspace will automatically be `source`d.

If you use more than one workspace you may encounter some issues if you do this for every workspace you use so you'll probably want to manually `source` your workspace in that case.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1